# Как придавать стили диалоговому окну, чтобы оно всё время на виду было

Tags: css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Существует кнопка ( точнее a href стилизированный под кнопку), при её нажатии появляется диалоговое окно, мне нужно задать стили диалогового окна, но при попытке написать эти стили ( margin, padding, line-height итд), нужно обновить страницу, опять нажать на кнопку вызова диалогового окна и посмотреть как поменялись стили. Даже когда пользуюсь плагином Live Server, окно закрывается и чтобы посмотреть измененные стили, приходится опять нажимать кнопку вызова диалогового окна ( Реализовано через fancybox ). Как сделать так чтобы окошко не пропадало , я мог вносить правки в стили и смотреть результат на лету, не обновляя и не нажимая кнопку вызова диалогового окна?

Comment: Что мешает при загрузке страницы вызвать тот же код, что и при нажатии на кнопку? И нет смысла для этого делать ее через <a>.

Comment: ну хоть какой совет, спасибо